# How can I pass the press of a character to a function? Python, Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

the function must accept three variables, I don’t know how to pass the button click

```
root.bind("<Key>", position(event= , x_global=x_global, y_global=y_global))
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've done any research before asking this question. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432)

Comment: you can use `lambda` to first capture the `event` argument and then in the `lambda` call this function with the `event` argument that was passed to `lambda` and the rest of the values, so something like `..., lambda e: position(event=e, ...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic syntax of bind is `widget.bind(event,func)`
In the case of a ButtonPress it is `widget.bind('<Button>',func)` where func is the address/id of the function to call. Without using lambda, eg

no parameters/'variables'

```
def func(e):         #e is the event that is passed to func by the bind function  
    pass

widget.bind('<Button>',func)
```

3 parameters

```
from functools import partial

def func(e,fx,fy,fz):
    pass

x=1
y=2
z=3
widget.bind('<Button>',partial(func, fx=x,fy=y,fz=z))
```

`partial` is a handy functools function that allows the passing of arguments/variables along with the func id parameter to the function that bind works with to call.